# Enhancement as in the increase

Tags: meaning

Elon Musk has recently posted a [comment](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/959585626071842817) on Twitter, wondering under what name to include a flamethrower he had sold on a shipment manifest, so it gets past the custom services. He then proposes "Temperature Enhancement Device" as an option.
I immediately thought he meant the 'enhancement', as in increasing the tempertaure, but after failing to find any plausible defition of the word 'enhancement' in this sense, I now have doubts about it.

Did Elon Musk mean a "temperature increasing device" or he implied the flamethrower as a "temperture control/regulation unit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enhance):

> Enhance:
>
> To augment or make something greater.

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/enhance):

> Enhance:
>
> To raise to a higher degree; intensify; magnify:

*Enhance* can mean *intensify*, so *enhancement* can mean *intensification* . Your first interpretation makes much more sense in the context: "*A temperature intensification device*".

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!
I suppose I wasn't sure the word 'enhance' could be with something as quantitative as temperature, but now I have my doubts dispelled.

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad I could help you out. Just curious, where did you look for the definition of enhancement before posting?

Answer (score 0):

With his temperature-enhancing flamethrower, Musk is making a humorous allusion to the Reagan era euphemism *[revenue enhancement](http://www.investorwords.com/8337/revenue_enhancement.html)*, which meant "[tax increase](http://www.taxhistory.org/thp/readings.nsf/ArtWeb/A38B36DCADF2A40B852578C60059C2E1?OpenDocument)" and fooled absolutely no one.

> The [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1981/10/21/us/a-euphemist-takes-a-bow.html) quickly tracked down the source of Reagan's new tax terminology. "The Reagan Administration's fiscal euphemist has been run to ground," the paper reported. "He is Lawrence A. Kudlow, who says he coined 'revenue enhancement,' the euphemism for tax increase used by the White House last month."

While the expression certainly predates the Reagan Era, its usage skyrocketed [during the 80s.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=revenue%20enhancement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crevenue%20enhancement%3B%2Cc0) Musk's similarly constructed euphemism for a flamethrower certainly alludes to it.